# Geoxml3 Shows Unable to retrieve Kml file

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding, kml, geoxml3

i went through lots of answers posted regarding the below question.
i wanted to retrieve the kml file from the local and so i used [geoxml](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3#svn%2Fbranches%2Fpolys)

var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({ map: map });

```
myParser.parse('indiastatev2.kml');
```

here is the code which i am trying to make work
my file is stored here in this folder [image: here]

i am not able to get the file path to pass in 
here are the solution which i tried doing it in different ways

```
myParser.parse('~/Content/KmlData/indiastatev2.kml');
myParser.parse('../../Content/KmlData/indiastatev2.kml');
```

none of them is working

this is what i am getting each time
[image: error]

here is my script [image: this]

i had already tried putting down the kml file in same folder but it didnt work

please suggest me something to make it work

Comment: How can we help if we don't know where your script is in the folder structure?

Comment: @MrUpsidown my script is working well only the thing is m not able to get the path of the my file which i need to parse, already posted the pictures, still if u need you need to see my script placement i can edit the post

Comment: Obviously you need a *relative path* to your kml file. This depends on where the script which contains `myParser.parse('indiastatev2.kml')` is located. So yes, edit your question with at least a screenshot that shows where your JS file is located.

Comment: Have you tried putting the KML file in the same directory as the webpage/script?  If you want it in a different directory, it needs to have a relative path to it from the location the page is loading from.  Is your web server set up to serve KML files?

Comment: [Example loading KML file in same directory as loaded page](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_KML_samples_test.html) (on a webserver)

Comment: @geocodezip where can i see the source code of above example  ?

Comment: @MrUpsidown i have already showed u where my kml files are located

Comment: view-source on the page